# Editing rows in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm not sure if this is considered as a noob question, but i'm trying to understand, how come when i execute a query like this in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT t1.id, FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.t_stamp/1000) as time_stamp, t1.value
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.colid
WHERE t1.colid = "123" 
AND
DATE(from_unixtime(t1.t_stamp/1000)) BETWEEN "2014-03-24" AND "2014-03-25"
```

I can't directly edit the rows, I mean that the Edit, Copy, Delete icons are not showing and I tried editing the rows but the change didn't apply

Then I tried another query like this

```
SELECT id, value, t_stamp
FROM table2 
WHERE DATE(from_unixtime(t_stamp/1000)) 
BETWEEN "2014-03-24" AND "2014-03-25" 
AND id = "123"
```

and then with that query i could edit the rows. Is there an option that I need to activate so that the Edit, Copy, and Delete icons is always showing and that I can always directly edit the rows?

Comment: I don't believe phpmyadmin supports edits on result sets from joins.

Comment: ... neither with functions applied.

Comment: As of i know, phpMyAdmin only allows editing row if all rows are from **one** table only. It won't support from multiple tables.